# How to stack two columns for grouping?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df` that represents a graph with nodes A, B, C and D. Each node belongs to a group 1 or 2:

```
src   dst   group_src   group_dst
A     B     1           1
A     B     1           1
B     A     1           1
A     C     1           2
C     D     2           2
D     C     2           2
```

I need to calculate the distinct number of nodes and the number of edges per group. The result should be the following:

```
group   nodes_count    edges_count
1       2              3
2       2              2
```

The edge A->C is not considered because the nodes belong to different groups.

I do not know how to stack the columns `group_src` and `group_dst` in order to group by unique column `group`. Also I do not know how to calculate the number of edges inside the group.

```
df
  .groupBy("group_src","group_dst")
  .agg(countDistinct("srcId","dstId").as("nodes_count"))
```

Comment: Is there any other idea how to calculate `edges_count`?

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be necessary to use two steps:

```
val edges = df.filter($"group_src" === $"group_dst")
  .groupBy($"group_src".as("group"))
  .agg(count("*").as("edges_count"))

val nodes = df.select($"src".as("id"), $"group_src".as("group"))
  .union(df.select($"dst".as("id"), $"group_dst".as("group"))
  .groupBy("group").agg(countDistinct($"id").as("nodes_count"))

nodes.join(edges, "group")
```

You can accomplish "stacking" of columns by using `.union()` after selecting specific columns.

Comment: `join` in the last line seems to be incomplete. also, `.groupBy("group_src".as("group"))` should be `.groupBy($"group_src".as("group"))`. please correct it. thanks.

Comment: Also `.agg(count("edges_count")` fails because `edges_count` does not exist.

Comment: Maybe it should be rather `.agg(count("*").as("edges_count"))`?

Comment: Sorry about that, just a typo. You are correct. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: With the corrected `.groupBy()` in the `edges` line, the final join should correctly result in the table you were looking for (unless I've introduced more syntax errors that we haven't noticed yet).